# Are hardcoded conditions optimized by JVM in Android?

Tags: java, android, performance

Due to debugging reason most parts of the code in my application has this recurrent portion of code:

```
public static final boolean DEBUG = true; // just created once in a "Utility" class

  if (Utility.DEBUG)
     Log.d("TIMER", /*string message that is strictly related to context*/);
```

Now, if the boolean values turn to `false` this becomes dead code. My question is if in this case the Android compiler would do basics optimizations such as constant folding and dead code remotion?

If the answer is no, what is the best way to whip out in release phase the debugging logs?

Comment: If `Utility.DEBUG`is a constant as indicated by your code, the dead code should already be removed by the java compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; in the case of `static final` fields the compiler can and will remove the unreachable section. If you [examine the byte-code](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer) you can validate this yourself.

Comment: To make that point clear: It's not the JVM, it's the Java compiler eliminating the dead code, before any Android-specific software comes into play.